# Reference 3rd-party C++ DLL into VS 2013 Project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I've been provided a DLL that has been written in C++. Along with the DLL I receive the required input parms and expected output as well as a .h include file.

Can't seem to get it included as a Reference in my project. My procedure is to right click References and Add Reference, click Browse and then double click on the DLL. The error I get is:

> A reference to 'c:......\dll' could not be added. Please make sure
>   that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM
>   component.

The problem is likely due to the name mangling of C++, but I'm not sure how to overcome the problem. I've been told by the author of the DLL that it was written for another customer who ran into the same issue, but was eventually successful in getting it referenced. I don't have access to that 'customer' and was wondering if anyone had suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a reference is not how you link to this unmanaged DLL from your C# code. Instead you need to either:

1. Translate the header file to C# p/invoke calls, or
2. Create a C++/CLI wrapper around the unmanaged DLL and add a reference to that from your C# project. This option would typically involve linking to the .lib import library for the DLL which should be supplied with the DLL.

Comment: David, is there a performance consideration? One way better than the other? Or does this not make a difference?

Comment: C++/CLI is more likely to be faster, as a general rule. In real world situations, the call overhead is rarely a bottleneck. Usually the decision is made based on which is the most convenient.

Comment: David, I do not have the source code for the C++ DLL and I can't be sure at this time if there is a wrapper within it that can be referenced by my C# app. I downloaded DependencyWalker from dependencywalker.com, but really don't know what I'm looking at with it. I was given the .h file for the DLL and just received the .LIB for it as well. I've searched for examples/how to's, but they seem to assume I have the source code for the C++ project. Do I have to create a class(es) in my C# project that define the strongly typed input/output objects of the C++ DLL?

Comment: You write an adapter. On the managed side are C++/CLI classes. They wrap up the unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand better, I really just don't have a clue how to write an adapter for this or what the classes are you are pointing me to. Are you aware of any links that apply to what I'm needing to do?